# Only display some data Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I just discovered Sonata and it seems really cool, but I can't find how to do simples things.

For example I have a list of items with a one to many to an user entity, is it possible to only display items who belongs to the current user ?

In this same Admin I would like to display more fields if the user has an admin role for example.

To finish is it possible to display some admin parts only for some roles, for example I only want user with a role admin on my userAdmin.

Comment: Its all possible in sonata admin you just have to dig documentation

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thank for your answer, I already read the doc, I think the third part is in the security part, I can find it. But for the two first points, maybe in the batch actions ? I don't understand really how does it works

Comment: For first point if you wish to filter listing you can use `createQuery( context ='list')`,for admin class, to display user related things you can get user from security context and alter query for related records to show additional fields in formmapper of admin you can get user first then check his/her role by using `isGranted()` call and add additional fields in formmapper object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter listing you have to use createQuery in your admin class, for exemple :

```
 public function createQuery($context = 'list') {
    $user = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->andWhere($query->getRootAlias() .'.user =: user'));
    $query->setParameter('user', $user);

    return $query;
}
```

To display more fields depending in user roles you can do that in the formMapper for exemple:

```
if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATEUR'))
{
  $formMapper->addYourfields ....
}
```

Finaly to secure a hole area you can then use symfony ACL , fo exemple in security.yml you can do that :

```
- { path: ^/admin/, role:  [ROLE_ADMINISTRATEUR] }
```

You can read more about  [symfony ACL](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)

Comment: Thank, but for the last part I prefer using sonata roles